# Batch echo command to file doesn't escape

Tags: windows, batch-file, escaping, echo

I am writing a script to automate backup setup on new servers. I am not the batch guru, so it is kept rather simple (See here in complete for reference http://pastebin.com/D1zEP8dj). Everything works to the bit where I try to write another batch script to a file:

```
        (
        echo del "%BACKUP_SERVER%Snapshot-%%COMPUTERNAME%%\Week_before\*.*" /S /Q
        echo.
        echo move /Y "%BACKUP_SERVER%Snapshot-%%COMPUTERNAME%%\Full\*.*" "%BACKUP_SERVER%Snapshot-%%COMPUTERNAME%%\Week_before"
        echo move /Y C:\Scripts\Backup.log "%BACKUP_SERVER%Snapshot-%%COMPUTERNAME%%\Week_before"
        echo move /Y C:\Scripts\Backupdiff.log "%BACKUP_SERVER%Snapshot-%%COMPUTERNAME%%\Week_before"
        echo.
        echo.
        echo C:\Scripts\snapshot.exe C: "%BACKUP_SERVER%Snapshot-$computername\Full\$disk-Partition-$type.sna" --LogFile:C:\Scripts\Backup.log -L50000 -GX --usevss --AllWriters  
        echo @echo off
        echo    if %%errorlevel%% NEQ 0 (

        echo        echo Error while Backup at %%COMPUTERNAME%%.%%USERDOMAIN%%  ^| C:\Scripts\blat\blat.exe -server %BLAT_MAILSERVER%  -to info@abc.com -f backup@%BLAT_DOMAIN% -s "Error while Backup at %%COMPUTERNAME%%.%%USERDOMAIN%%" -attach C:\Scripts\Backup.log
        echo    )
        ) >full-backup.bat

    if %DO_DIFF_BACKUP%==y (
        (
            echo C:\Scripts\snapshot.exe C: %BACKUP_SERVER%\Snapshot-$computername\Diff\$disk-Partition-$type-$weekday.sna -h%BACKUP_SERVER%\Snapshot-$computername\Full\c-Partition-ful.hsh --LogFile:C:\Scripts\Backupdiff.log -L50000 -GX --usevss --AllWriters  
            echo @echo off
            echo    if %%%errorlevel%%% NEQ 0 (
            echo        echo Error while Backup at %%COMPUTERNAME%%.%%USERDOMAIN%%  ^| C:\Scripts\blat\blat.exe -server %BLAT_MAILSERVER%  -to info@abc.com -f backup@%BLAT_DOMAIN% -s "Error while Backup at %%COMPUTERNAME%%.%%USERDOMAIN%%" -attach C:\Scripts\Backupdiff.log
            echo    )
        ) >diff-backup.bat
    )
```

So when executing the script, it stops on the last line of this excerpt. The file full-backup.bat doesn't exist at all, but won't throw an error at all, while the file diff-backup.bat is written with the following content:

```
 C:\Scripts\snapshot.exe C: c:\test\Snapshot-$computername\Diff\$disk-Partition-$type-$weekday.sna -hc:\test\Snapshot-$computername\Full\c-Partition-ful.hsh -- LogFile:C:\Scripts\Backupdiff.log -L50000 -GX --usevss --AllWriters  
 @echo off
    if %0% NEQ 0 (
```

The internet says, to escape percents double them, to escape pipes ^|-them, etc. But it does not seem to change anything if I quote things, use escape signs at all - batch won't listen to me :(. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `echo    )` will close your code block, so you need to escape it too `echo ^)`

Comment: Just tried that, same result as before. Nevertheless you are right, how could I not see that?

Comment: `%%%errorlevel%%%` should be `%%errorlevel%%` and the last single parenthesis should be removed.

Comment: you have more errors in your script, ex. `if "%REPEAT_DOWNLOAD%"=="y"` will _never_ be true, please look at `delayed expansion`.

Comment: a lot of variables won't work, you cannot set a variable and use it in the same code block without `delayed expansion`. Moreover, you use the variable `"%CONFIRM_BACKUP_CONF%"` before defining it. You should revise your code and come back later.

Answer (score 1):

When you double the percent signs where you want to echo literally `%` and escaping all other special characters with `^`  it should work.

As you can't know if your variables contains also special characters, it would be the best to use delayed expansion here instead of percent expansion.
This works as all content is safe when expanded by delayed expansion

```
setlocal EnabledDelayedExpansion
(
    echo del "!BACKUP_SERVER!Snapshot-%%COMPUTERNAME%%\Week_before\*.*" /S /Q
    echo.
    echo move /Y "!BACKUP_SERVER!Snapshot-%%COMPUTERNAME%%\Full\*.*" "!BACKUP_SERVER!Snapshot-%%COMPUTERNAME%%\Week_before"
    echo move /Y C:\Scripts\Backup.log "!BACKUP_SERVER!Snapshot-%%COMPUTERNAME%%\Week_before"
    echo move /Y C:\Scripts\Backupdiff.log "!BACKUP_SERVER!Snapshot-%%COMPUTERNAME%%\Week_before"
    echo.
    echo.
    echo C:\Scripts\snapshot.exe C: "!BACKUP_SERVER!Snapshot-$computername\Full\$disk-Partition-$type.sna" --LogFile:C:\Scripts\Backup.log -L50000 -GX --usevss --AllWriters  
    echo @echo off
    echo    if %%errorlevel%% NEQ 0 (

    echo        echo Error while Backup at %%COMPUTERNAME%%.%%USERDOMAIN%%  ^| C:\Scripts\blat\blat.exe -server !BLAT_MAILSERVER!  -to info@abc.com -f backup@!BLAT_DOMAIN! -s "Error while Backup at %%COMPUTERNAME%%.%%USERDOMAIN%%" -attach C:\Scripts\Backup.log
    echo    ^)
)
```

Comment: While the script seems to output the text in the files now, the 'BACKUP_SERVER' variable will not be replaced with the string defined earlier.

Comment: Do you add the `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` line?

Comment: Do you get `!Backup_SERVER!` as text or an empty text? What happens when you add `set BACKUP_SERVER=TEST` just before the block?